# Merge multiple dictionaries to obtain an array of custom objects

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following 5 dictionaries

```
var serialsDict = [ Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3) : "860408ff",
             Source(address: 0, endpoint: 4) : "560410ff"]
var namesDict = [ Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3) : "SLIGHTR10",
             Source(address: 0, endpoint: 4) : "SLIGHTR09"]
var fwVersionsDict = [ Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3) : "FG01b",
             Source(address: 0, endpoint: 4) : "FG02c"]
var hwVersionDict = [ Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3) : "604a1r00",
             Source(address: 0, endpoint: 4) : "674b1r45"]
var typesDict = [ Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3) : 4,
             Source(address: 0, endpoint: 4) : 1]
```

where `Source` is

```
struct Source: Hashable {
    let address: Int
    let endpoint: Int
}
```

I have to merge the 5 dictionaries to obtain an array with 2 `FoundDevice` objects. Where `FoundDevice` is the following struct:

```
struct FoundDevice {
    
    let source: Source
    
    let serial: String
    let name: String
    let fwVersion: String
    let hwVersion: String
    let type: Int
}
```

For example the first element has to be

> FoundDevice(source: Source(address: 0, endpoint: 3), serial:
> "860408ff", name: "SLIGHTR10", fwVersion: "FG01b", hwVersion:
> "604a1r00", type: 4)

This is my current implementation:

```
serialsDict.keys.forEach { source in
    if let serial = serialsDict[source], let name = namesDict[source], let fwVersion = fwVersionsDict[source], let hwVersion = hwVersionDict[source], let type = typesDict[source] {
        devices.append(FoundDevice(source: source, serial: serial, name: name, fwVersion: fwVersion, hwVersion: hwVersion, type: type))
    }
}
```

Is there a smarter way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "trick" available, but you don't need to check for a value in one of the dictionaries again; you already have that.

```swift
extension FoundDevice {
  init?(
    source: Source,
    serial: String,
    names: [Source: String],
    fwVersions: [Source: String],
    hwVersions: [Source: String],
    types: [Source: Int]
  ) {
    guard
      let name = names[source],
      let fwVersion = fwVersions[source],
      let hwVersion = hwVersions[source],
      let type = types[source]
    else { return nil }
    
    self.init(
      source: source,
      serial: serial,
      name: name,
      fwVersion: fwVersion,
      hwVersion: hwVersion,
      type: type
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
serialsDict.compactMap {
  FoundDevice(
    source: $0.key,
    serial: $0.value,
    names: namesDict,
    fwVersions: fwVersionsDict,
    hwVersions: hwVersionDict,
    types: typesDict
  )
}
```

---

Addressing your comment below,

> my dictionaries could contain more keys than other. I have to create
> my object only if the key is in every dictionary.

The guard statement above handles that, no matter which of the dictionaries you use for iteration.

But if you have the intersection of the keys around, for whatever reason, which is…

```swift
let sources = [serialsDict, namesDict, fwVersionsDict, hwVersionDict]
  .reduce(into: Set(typesDict.keys)) {
    $0.formIntersection($1.keys)
  }
```

…then you can safely force unwrap.

```swift
extension FoundDevice {
  /// - Precondition: `source` is a key in all of the dictionaries.
  init(
    source: Source,
    serials: [Source: String],
    names: [Source: String],
    fwVersions: [Source: String],
    hwVersions: [Source: String],
    types: [Source: Int]
  ) {
    self.init(
      source: source,
      serial: serials[source]!,
      name: names[source]!,
      fwVersion: fwVersions[source]!,
      hwVersion: hwVersions[source]!,
      type: types[source]!
    )
  }
}

sources.map {
  FoundDevice(
    source: $0,
    serials: serialsDict,
    names: namesDict,
    fwVersions: fwVersionsDict,
    hwVersions: hwVersionDict,
    types: typesDict
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok! Sorry...my dictionaries could contain more keys than other. I have to create my object only if the key is in every dictionary.

Comment: I've addressed that below the divider line.

Comment: Thanks @Jessy. I think the former implementation is more safe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map one set of data to another set of a type. That would be map. But since you use dictionarys, we need compact map here.

```
let sources = serialsDict.map({ $0.key })

let foundDevices: [FoundDevice] = sources.compactMap({
    if let serial = serialsDict[$0],
       let name = namesDict[$0],
       let fwVersion = fwVersionsDict[$0],
       let hwVersion = hwVersionDict[$0],
       let typ = typesDict[$0] {
        return FoundDevice(source: $0, serial: serial, name: name, fwVersion: fwVersion, hwVersion: hwVersion, type: typ)
    }
    return nil 
})
```

Comment: I don't have to use necessarily dictionaries. But I didn't understand what's the alternative.

Comment: Querrying a key returns an optional, as the key might be not there. It is not bad, but requires to deal with the Optional<Source>

Comment: The if (or guard if you want) makes sure you have all values. There is no better solution as each of the dictionarys can have a different amount of entries

Comment: Thank you very much @Helge. I chose the @Jessy's solution only cause avoid to check for a value in one of the dictionaries again and because I like the idea of `init` in the `FoundDevice` extension. But your solution is valid too.

Comment: @HelgeBecker You don't need that `map` to get the keys from `serialsDict`, just use the `keys` property and `compactMap` on that: `let foundDevices = serialsDict.keys.compactMap {…}` as well as you can safely force unwrap the value from `serialDict` for every key in the `compactMap` closure.